# CloudKit compare record change tags

Tags: cloudkit

In my application I have a method, `getProfileRecordWithCompletion(...)completion` which returns the user profile record for the current user. I cache this record in my application and return the cached version if it exists, otherwise I retrieve it from the CloudKit database.

While this works, I would like to compare the change tag of the cached version to the one on the server, and retrieve it from the database if the cached version is outdated. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I did not. It seems you cannot use the change tags in the way I expected. Instead the preferred method is to use notifications to subscribe to any changes in the DB and sync those to your local cache. I currently don't do this, and hope users won't modify their profile on another device while running the app.